# Jquery Allow Empty space between Characters only on Key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hi how to allow empty characters between words only. I have tried but doesn't allow empty character anywhere.

**Jquery**

```js
 $('#txtName').keypress(function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Please Enter Alphabet');
        return false;
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtName">
```

It's for name validation. Thanks.

Comment: Look like your code working fine. what's the problem? , It allow white space already.

Comment: Problem was Don't allow space before name. And allow space between firstname and lastname. Example-(John Adams). We need space between the words.

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2HUV7/) ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly @Pedram. Could You post this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
/(\s{2,})|[^a-zA-Z']/g
```

```js
$('#txtName').keypress(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $(this).val($this.val().replace(/(\s{2,})|[^a-zA-Z0-9_']/g, ' ').replace(/^\s*/, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtName" />
```

From **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HUV7/)**

Answer (score 0):

use `Trim()` method, with this method you can remove any space in first and last of your string, then put equal to `null` or `white-space`
[Online demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5s8kzqe8/)

if you want just Regex with `/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g` you can get any white-space in first and last of your string then out not equal to `null` or `white-space` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fIsrTQ/4)

for more information see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: Used this code. It doesn't allow space in between of words.